# How can i send message to handler from a static function?

Tags: android

I know, this is again a repeated question but my case it is different question.

I have a class abc with a static function & a Handler. Earlier i couldn't able call handler from a static function. Then i googled for **Access a non-static function from a static function** & found an solution is to create an instance of class & access non-static variable. But now, why, i m getting this error.

**`E/AndroidRuntime(13343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`**

```
public class abc
 {    
    static public void Instantiate()
    {
         abc xyz = new abc();
         xyz.handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);      **//GETTING ERROR IN THIS LINE**
    }

    public Handler handler = new Handler() 
        {
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
                {
                        switch (msg.what)
                        {
                        }
                 }
        }

}
```

**My Question: How can i send message to *handler* from a static function?**

**Thankx.**

Comment: from where are you calling this `Instantiate()` method? Generally you are supposed to call it from an Async Task/ worker thread (the one other than the main UI Thread).

Comment: I'd suggest you tell us what you're *really* trying to do rather. We might be abe to help you work around this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check the place where you are doing this:

```
abc.Instantiate();
```

and replace it with

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        abc.Instantiate();
    }
});
```

I hope you're calling it from an Activity

***Some Explanation (****quoting* ***bicska88) :)***

---

What causes the problem, doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you send a message to a `Handler` object from within a static function. The problem is that you send a message to the handler from a thread that has not called `Looper.prepare()` (as the error message says, the thread doesn't have a **`message loop`**). This may be fixed by explicitly calling `Looper.prepare()` before-while, or by running the code on the UIThread.

---

Comment: Note that this will not work, since the newly created thread doesn't have a message loop associated with it, and will still throw the above mentioned exception.

Comment: hehehee.. Thankx @bicska88.. but magically its worked for me.. Thankx  for your answer Sherif. Atleast i got a clue of what i shud in my application.

Comment: It is working because the UI thread **HAS** a message loop. Note that my answer included a fully-working code sample.

Comment: This answer is not correct, since the error message already tells us that you have created the handler on a thread that is different from the UI thread. The `Handler` object belongs to the thread where you created it. This way you create it on the UI thread, so the `Handler` object belongs to this thread. If you wanted this answer, then your question is ambiguous, inexact and indistinctive. Read the documentation and probably you will see my point.

Answer (score 2):

try defining the handler as

```
final static Handler handler = new Handler() { ... };
```

Answer (score 2):

What causes the problem, doesn't have anything to do with the fact that you send a message to a `Handler` object from within a static function. The problem is that you send a message to the handler from a thread that has not called `Looper.prepare()` (as the error message says, the thread doesn't have a **`message loop`**). To fix this, do the following:

```
public class abc
{    
    public Handler handler;

    static public void Instantiate()
    {
        abc xyz = new abc();
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler() 
        {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
            {
                switch (msg.what)
                {

                }
            }
        }
        xyz.handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        Looper.loop();
    }
}
```

Documentation can be found at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) link.