# How to show Dialog from a static method

Tags: java, android, dialog, cocos2d-x, android-context

In my game, which is done for both Android and IOS using `cocos2dx`, I have to show video(for Android). I am planning to show it in Dialog(on top of game view). Problem is that, I don't have any Activity referenced to show Dialog(as Dialogs can only be shown in Activities). Even though, In cocos2dx lib folder, there is a `Cocos2dxActivity` but I am not getting how to make use of it. From C++ code, I am calling a static method from Java class as below

```
void LMJNICommunicator::showVideo()
{
     LOGD("initialiseDatabase inside LMJNICommunicator");

     jmethodID methodID = 0;
     JNIEnv *pEnv = 0;
     pEnv = getJNIEnv();
     jclass ret = pEnv->FindClass("com/mobinius/lostmonstersclass/LMDatabaseDataManager");
     methodID = pEnv->GetStaticMethodID(ret, "showVideo", "()V");

     if (! methodID)
     {
          LOGD("Failed to find static method id of %s", "showVideo");
          return;
     }

     pEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(ret,methodID);
     pEnv->DeleteLocalRef(ret);

}
```

Static method(which is in normal Java class) which I am calling from C++ code

```
Class LMDatabaseDataManager {

    public static void showVideo() {

         Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Cocos2dxActivity.getInstance());
         dialog.show();
        // getting Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare() error
    }
}
```

I tried to make use of `Handler` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483275/how-can-i-send-message-to-handler-from-a-static-function) but did not get result(got same error in that post).
Also tried to get a static `Context` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android).

So, is my way correct? If not correct, please suggest a way how can I implement the same. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Finally got answer for this. Earlier I tried running on UI thread with Application static context as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android) link but did not get... with Cocos2dxActivity activity instance I got it.

```
Class LMDatabaseDataManager {

    public static void showVideo() {        

    Cocos2dxActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Cocos2dxActivity.getInstance());
            dialog.show();            
        }
    });

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you not overlaying your video on an Activity?

Comment: no actually... as I explained in question, thr is a activity named Cocos2dxActivity in which GLSurfaceView n all are running... I dont know whether i can make use of it or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding the appropriate lines in Cocos2dxActivity:

```
public class Cocos2dxActivity extends Activity {
    private static Cocos2dxActivity instance = null;
   @Override public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
     ...
     this.instance = this;
     }

     public static Cocos2dxActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
     }



}
```

When you want to create your dialog:

```
if (Cocos2dxActivity.getInstance() != null)  {
    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog(Cocos2dxActivity.getInstance());
    // rest of your dialog code goes here
}
```

Comment: thanks for d response... once i tried above by getting Application global context as shown in my question second link but did not get result... anyway, i wl try your answer n let u know

Comment: I tried your answer... its throwing error "cant create handler inside a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

Comment: Thank u very much for your time... I solved the problem. Earlier I tried running on UI thread with Application static context as in question second link but did not get... with Cocos2dActivity activity instance I got it...

Comment: I think that **this.instance = null;** should be called from within the **onDestroy()** method. Otherwise a memory leak will occur once the activity is dead, because a reference to a dead activity will be kept.

More info: [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.bg/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)